# How to implement a book library with multi-threaded program?

Tags: concurrency

Say there is a book library. People can borrow books and return books. There are one or more copies from each book.

Lets assume that:
1. If a person comes to the library with a list of books, he won't leave the library without all of the books.
2. It isn't possible that on some borrower's list, there are books of which the library doesn't have at least a single copy.

We agree that the borrowers are represented by threads.

I can think of only one option to implement it:

```
public synchronized void borrowBooks(final ArrayList<Item> booksList)
{
    try {
        while (!areBooksPresent(booksList)) {
            this.wait();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

    for (Book book : booksList) {
        Book libraryBook = findBook(book);
        /* Decrement the book's amount in the library */
        libraryBook.decAmount();
    }
}


public synchronized void returnBooks(final ArrayList<Item> booksList)
{
    for (Book book : booksList) {
        Book libraryBook = findBook(book);
        /* increment the book's amount in the library */
        libraryBook.incAmount();
        /* Notify to all awaiting threads that the monitor is freed */
        this.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

As you can see, as a thread starts to borrow his books, the whole library is locked and no other thread can borrow at the same time. We also guarantee that in the `for` loop for borrowing the books, it's impossible that a book is not present.

The main problem is that we lose the whole point of multi-threaded program when we lock the whole library every time a thread borrows books.

The other alternatives seem to cause deadlocks.

Do you have any suggestion for more concurrent solution which is also safe and has liveness?

Answer (score 1):

Keep a structure for each book allowing a thread to block until a particular book is returned.

Have each borrower wait for at least one of the books it needs. When it wakes up, have it check to see if all the books it needs are available. If so, it should take them all and leave. If not, it should pick one of the books it needs that are not available and wait for it.

This may, however, cause some borrowers to wait forever. To avoid this, use a special priority algorithm. Keep a queue of the borrowers in arrival order. Put new borrowers to the back of the line. Then simply implement one rule -- if there is any book the head borrower needs, only the head borrower may take it.

This will leave one special case you have to handle: A borrower is not the head borrower, all the books it needs are available, but it cannot take them because one of the books is needed by the head borrower. In this case, have a special "head borrower has left" event that the borrower can wait for. When a borrower gets all its books, check if it was the head borrower, and if so unblock all threads waiting on that event.

Any given borrower, at any time, has some finite number of borrowers ahead of it. That number cannot increase. And it will decrease because one of the borrowers ahead of you (the head one) has absolute priority and every book is returned eventually. No borrower ever holds a book while it waits for other books. So this should be deadlock free.

Comment: You don't need a queue for every book. But you do (potentially) need an event for every book that's been borrowed that a thread is waiting for.